# sorting list of Object class before adding the list into the gridModel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

The code is given below .........

```
private List<EmployeeAllRec> listg;
private List<Employee> list;
private List<Employee> gridModel;
private Map<String, String> json;

 public String showAllRecord() {

        records = 30;
        rows = 10;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        EmployeeAllRec rs = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            listg = new ArrayList();
            List emp = session.createQuery("from Employee e").list();

            int c=0;
            //code for adding the data into the list
            for (Iterator iterator = emp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Employee e1 = (Employee) iterator.next();
                System.out.println(e1.getName());
                rs = new EmployeeAllRec();

                rs.setName(e1.getName());
                rs.setEmail(e1.getEmail());
                rs.setDob(e1.getDob());
                rs.setAddress(e1.getAddress());
                rs.setGender(e1.getGender());
                rs.setAge(e1.getAge());
                rs.setCountry(e1.getCountry());
                rs.setContact(e1.getContact());
                rs.setWebsite(e1.getWebsite());
                System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&---i m on it " + rs.getName());
                listg.add(rs);
           }

           setGridModel(listg);

           // some stuff
```

My problem is that I need to sort the "listg" variable into descending order before adding it into the variable setGridModel....

Comment: So did you already look at `java.util.Collections`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects that are added into listg are taken from a DB, I would suggest ordering it through the HQL query.DB ordering is faster then in memory ordering (using a comparator), and in this case you can apply approach.

So the HQL query will look smth like "FROM Employee e ORDER BY... DESC"

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a compareTo on your object that sorts them in descending order.
2. Call Collections.sort(listg) once it's populated.

PS: Consider using generics in your collections if possible.